# How do I attach an external VMDK disk to a guest image, from within the guest image?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, vmware-server

I have a Linux guest image that starts up, with only the OS drive.  The actual ESX server has many VMDKs (I know the IDs of them).  In my workflow, I need to on demand, from within the guest, attach one of those VMDKs to the guest instance.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From a high level perspective:

- Pick your favorite language/tool to access the VMware API with and embed it in the image
- Have a way for the image to get credentials needed to perform the action against VMware (embedded in the image or retrieved from a secrets vault). If the script is being run interactively, this could also just be from memory from the user.
- Write your script that utilizes the VMware API and credentials to attach the VMDK

In other words, exactly the same way you would do it programmatically *not* from within the guest.